# How to dynamically change the action attribute of form when a base layer is clicked in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, forms, leaflet, addeventlistener, buttonclick

I am having trouble attaching click events in Leaflet overlay layers. My HTML has a `<form>` with a `<button>` that links to the larger map (external website) when clicked. Since I have several base layers, I want to change the `action` attribute so that the links point to the appropriate sites when the layer is clicked in the layers control:

```
<div id='map'></div>
<form id='viewlarger'
  action='https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/14.5906/120.9799'
  method='get'
  target='_blank'>
    <button>View larger map</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [14.5906, 120.9799],
  zoom: 15,
  layers: [stamenTerr]
});

var base = {
  "Stamen Terrain": stamenTerr,
  "Stamen Toner": stamenToner,
};

L.control.layers(base).addTo(map);

var largerButton = document.getElementById('viewlarger');

var stamenTerr = L.tileLayer('http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: 'abcd'
});

var stamenToner = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
  attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: 'abcd',
  ext: 'png'
});
```

I tried using `addEventListener` but I cannot get it to correctly change the links when another base layer in the layers controls is clicked:

```
stamenTerr.addEventListener('click', function () {
  largerButton.action = "http://maps.stamen.com/terrain/#15/14.5906/120.9799";
});

stamenToner.addEventListener('click', function () {
  largerButton.action = "http://maps.stamen.com/toner/#15/14.5906/120.9799";
});
```

Could you please check on how to fix this? Thank you.

EDIT:

I tried this but the link is not changed:

```
map.on('click', function () {
  if (map.hasLayer(tileStamenToner)) {
    viewLMapBtn.action = http://maps.stamen.com/toner/#15/14.5906/120.9799";
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Leaflet, `L.TileLayer`s don't have a `click` event (or any other kind of mouse/pointer events).

Instead, use a `map.on('click', ...);` event handler, and use `map.hasLayer(...)` to query visible `TileLayer`s

Comment: I'm sorry I am having difficulty understanding how to use the code you have provided. I edited the question. Please check.